# Universal function with multiple array arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a universal function with multiple numpy array arguments using python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.constants

pi = np.pi
i = 0.+1.j
c = scipy.constants.c

lam = 0.860e-6
f_c = c/lam

def refl_general(array_r, array_L, f):
    array_phi = 2*pi*array_L*f/c
    phi_sum = np.sum(array_phi)
    exp_sum = np.exp(i*phi_sum)

    r_all = np.prod(array_r)
    r_in = array_r[0] 
    r_except_in = np.prod(array_r[1:]) 
    
    return (-r_in + r_except_in*exp_sum)/(1-r_all*exp_sum)
```

This function works like `refl_general(np.array([np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)]), np.array([1, 1, 1]), f_c)`.
I'd like to plot `refl_general(np.array([np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)]), np.array([L/3, L/3, L/3]), f_c)` against `L = np.linspace(lam, 3*lam, 1000)` without remaking the function.
I'd like to apply this function to each elements of L and get an array of each output. In other words, I want to write the following without using `for`.

```
array_L = np.linspace(lam, 3*lam, 1000)
array_signal = np.array([])
for L in array_L:
    signal = np.abs(refl_general(np.array([np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)]), np.array([L/3, L/3, L/3]), f_c))
    array_signal = np.append(array_signal, signal)
plt.plot(array_L, array_signal)
```

Simply writing `refl_general(np.array([np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)]), np.array([L/3, L/3, L/3]), f_c)` doesn doesn't achieve the desired output since `np.array([L/3, L/3, L/3])` becomes a two-dimensional array

For example, I already know how to create a universal function using np.frompyfunc.
But, this also doesn't work as expected because the argument `np.array([L/3, L/3, L/3])` is a two-dimensional array.

Comment: `def func(*args):` is a way of accepting multiple arguments.

Comment: `np.array([x, y, z])` makes a 2d array if the arrays are equal size 1d arrays.  If they differ in shape, the result may be a 1d (3,) object dtype array - along with a warning.  Making such an array from equal size arrays is possible, but a bit trickier.  Object dtype arrays are very much like lists, and math on such arrays is hit-or-miss.  Object dtype arrays come up often on SO, usually when people make them by mistake.  `np.frompyfunc` makes this kind of object dtype array.

Comment: Can `def func(*args):` be used in this situation? The definition of the function depends on the number of the arguments. For example, the definitions between `f(r1, r2, r3, L1, L2, L3, f)` and `f(r1, r2, L1, L2, f)`  should be different.

Comment: `args` will be a list.  You can check its `len`.  Also unpacking, `r1,r2,r3...=args`

Comment: Could you please write a specific definition of the function using  `*argus`?